# Salesforce not letting find country from a relationship, but allows name and id

Tags: salesforce

I am running the following query in salesforce to get the country

```
SELECt name, owner.country from lead
```

This gives the following error:

```
No such column 'country' on entity 'Name'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

However this works just fine if I do

```
SELECt name, owner.id from lead
SELECt name, owner.username from lead
SELECt name, owner.name from lead
```

It gives the data

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to the polymorphic relationship. If you have carefully read the error you are getting, you may have noted that the entity is `Name`, it's not `User` (as I also expected sometime back). 
[The `Name`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_name.htm) object is used to retrieve information from related records where the related record may be from more than one object type.

> For example, the owner of a case can be either a user or a group
>   (queue)

`Who`, `What` and `Owner` relationship fields will be used to access this `Name` object and it can't be accessed directly. And the error you are getting is due to this `Name` entity doesn't have a field called `country` as you can see in the documentation.